# How to add a tagging or label(the same thing in a cad file) through ezdxf or dxfwrite of python?

Tags: python, cad, dxf

I want to born a file which can be open by CAD software.

I choose the  library named 'ezdxf'.

I get trouble when I want to add a label(or tagging, I mean,the function provide by CAD software to show the begin and end point of a line segment).

I had tried to read the documents of the 'ezdxf',but did not found anything about the label or tagging(en,with my poor English and the Google translation).

So, the question:

If I want to born a file like 'XXX.dxf',which library of python has more function(s) and provide the function above ---- add a label or tagging?

Comment: Now ,use C# through CADLIB to make cad picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Drawing with [ezdxf](http://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dwgmanagement.html#create-new-drawings):

```
import ezdxf
drawing = ezdxf.new(dxfversion='AC1009')
```

Supported DXF versions:

- AC1009   AutoCAD R12
- AC1015   AutoCAD R2000
- AC1018   AutoCAD R2004
- AC1021   AutoCAD R2007
- AC1024   AutoCAD R2010
- AC1027   AutoCAD R2013
- AC1032   AutoCAD R2018

The title of dxfwrite at github is:

> Outdated DXF R12 writer, please switch to ezdxf

There exists no library which provides exact what you need, ezdxf is just an interface to the DXF format not a CAD application.

Comment: Sorry,In my search,Mybe what I want is, about the LinearDimension,'Biao Zhu' in Chinese.In your words,ezdxf is just an interface to the DXF format not a CAD application,what does this mean?It means I could not make a LinearDimension directly?

Comment: I searched from the documents,I get the function:add_XXX_dim,but 'pass' in it.Also ,I found LinearDimension,which is similar to the 'Biao Zhu' in DXF format (Chinese version).I tried to a = LinearDimension(),and add_ entity(),but failed.Could you explain the Working principle ,such as the entities and others?Thanks a lot.

Comment: Creating DIMENSION entities is not supported yet, but it is on the todo list.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I found a demo about DIMENSION in your github,which is useful when using 'new' by a  'R12' ,but not useful by other version,which is also useful for me.Thanks for your library and your answer.